# Sources.list для Debian 8.11 jessie Не удаётся обновить

Tags: debian

Есть арендованный сервер Debian. Нужно его обновить.
Изначально стояли зеркала яндекса, обновить не удавалось.
Попробовал несколько других зеркал, также ошибки.
Я нуб, прошу помощи.

**Версия**

```
root@debian-serv-1:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:        8.11
Codename:       jessie
```

**Текущий сорц лист:**

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security oldstable/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security oldstable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie/updates main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
```

**При apt-get update выдаёт:**

```
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Ign http://deb.debian.org oldstable InRelease
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Hit http://deb.debian.org oldstable-updates InRelease
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Hit http://deb.debian.org oldstable/updates InRelease
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
Hit http://deb.debian.org oldstable Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/updates/main Sources [310 kB]
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie Release
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/updates/main amd64 Packages [680 kB]
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie/updates Release
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/updates/main Translation-en [343 kB]
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports Release
Hit http://deb.debian.org oldstable Release
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/main Sources [7,063 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/contrib Sources [50.4 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/non-free Sources [99.2 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/main amd64 Packages [6,818 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/contrib amd64 Packages [49.8 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/non-free amd64 Packages [83.2 kB]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/contrib Translation-en [38.3 kB]
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/main Sources
Get:11 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/main Translation-en [4,581 kB]
Get:12 http://deb.debian.org oldstable/non-free Translation-en [72.0 kB]
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/oldstable-updates/InReleas                         e  Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong so                         urces.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease                           Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sourc                         es.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/updates/main/source                         /Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary                         -amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/sour                         ce/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/bina                         ry-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.12 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used                          instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Время debian jessie уже вышло. [Официально](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases) он стал end of life ещё 17 июня 2018 года. Отдельная команда [Debian Long Term Support](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) поддерживает некоторые репозитории ещё до 30 июня 2020 года для некоторых архитектур. Но это касается [только репозиториев из списка](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Остальные как можно видеть не поддерживаются и были уже удалены с зеркал. Всё-таки они занимают прилично места на дисках, которые кто-то содержит за свой счёт не взимая платы с пользователей.

Так же есть архив http://archive.debian.org/debian/ , где сохраняются пакеты исходных кодов, а некоторое время ещё доступны и бинарные пакеты. Так, в настоящее время пакеты для jessie должны быть ещё доступны в репозитории:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
```

Но обновление системы до актуальных выпусков планировать надо. До 9.х или возможно лучше сразу до 10.х (релиз ожидается летом)