# Недоступен открытый ключ для следующих ID ключей(2)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt-get, gitlab-ci, gpg

Вопрос такого типа уже существует, но всё, что предлагали сделать там для исправления не сработало у меня.

Пытаюсь обновить пакеты на ubuntu в docker контейнере и появляется следующая ошибка:

```
$ apt-get update
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [16.3 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [1652 B]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [77.3 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports Release
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [20 B]
Get:6 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [992 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Fetched 10.2 MB in 6s (1525 kB/s)
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
KEY-ID
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Пытался обновить дебиан пакет, пытался вот это вводить:

```
- gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv KEY-ID
- gpg --export --armor X | apt-key add -
```

Но в ответ снова ошибка:

```
$ gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv KEY-ID
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 331F7F50 from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

Подскажите, что может мне помочь ?

Comment: вам может помочь образ с хотя бы olstable-версией. на данный момент — [stretch](https://www.debian.org/releases/). а ещё лучше — stable-версией. на данный момент — buster.

Comment: стоп. у вас в дистрибутиве ubuntu подключены репозитории от древней версии debian? не получится у вас ничего обновить, даже если брать пакеты из [arhchive.debian.org](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982835/178576)

Comment: Не в курсе, что есть в дистрибутиве ubuntu т.к. он был скачан в виде изображения при пуле `java:8` на докер контейнер.

Comment: А можно ссылку на `Dockerfile`, в котором прописана такая дичь?

Comment: Запульте `java:8`